# MessageBox producing different output than Cout C++

Tags: c++, io

I am trying to load the name of an image using its VM address by calling `GetModuleFileName()` which seems to return the value correctly into a `TCHAR[]` array. I am able to display the data correctly using `MessageBox()` but `cout <<` seems to display some funky hexadecimal number.

```
TCHAR buf[MAX_PATH];
HMODULE hProc = LoadLibrary(TEXT("kernel32.dll"));
GetModuleFileName(hProc, buf, MAX_PATH);
cout << buf; //Produces the odd number
MessageBox(NULL, buf, NULL, MB_OK); //Produces correct filepath
FreeLibrary(hProc);
```

Am I supposed to set a flag for `cout` so it knows to print it correctly? Thank you!

Comment: In modern Windows programming (as of after the year 2000), don't use `TCHAR`. Use e.g. `wchar_t`. Then you know better what you're doing and what you're dealing with.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the difference? Compatibility?

Comment: `TCHAR` is a macro (pure text substitution) that is defined as either `char` or `wchar_t`, depending on whether the symbol `UNICODE` was defined when you included the relevant header, usually `<windows.h>`. Similarly, `TEXT` adds `L` prefix or not. This means that code that works with `UNICODE` defined, may and probably will not compile when `UNICODE` is not defined. The `T` scheme originally supported Windows 9x, but as of 2011 it is just a problematic extra layer of obfuscation. For example, it prevented you from knowing that you dealt with `wchar_t`. Cheers & hth.,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably you need to use `wcout`, because your `TCHAR` might be unicodish. Or convert it.

Comment: Had a feeling it was something simple like that. Never knew about `wcout` until now, thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I haven't seen your answer, when posting mine.. and I cannot delete it, because I've already deleted 5 my posts today....

Comment: Is there a `tcout` or something in Windows, that'd be `cout` for ANSI and `wcout` for Unicode?

Comment: There should be no `TCHAR` instead :) Actually, I don't know, I don't use windows for eons now. If there's nothing like that, you can #define it, perhaps.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you will have better luck with

```
std::wcout << buf;
```